# "Bad allocation" in OpenCV in VS2017 Debug Mode

Tags: c++, opencv, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently working with C++/OpenCV using VS2017 and had no problems reading a video-stream from a file (using `VideoCapture`).

However, I am getting the following error message, when building in `Debug Mode`:

```
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:901)
warning: pΦ∩á╬ (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:902)
[ERROR:0] VIDEOIO(cvCreateCapture_MSMF(filename)): raised C++ exception:

bad allocation
```

I am wondering where the error might be coming from, as the program works perfectly fine in `Release Mode`.

I might add, that the video files I am testing with are approx. `2.7 GB` to `8.8 GB` large.

Is this an allocator issue inside the VS2017-Debugger hitting the `int32_max` limit 
 of `2³¹ bit` (even though it is a 64Bit-Process)?

Comment: Are you linking with the debug build of OpenCV?

Comment: nope, I pre-build the OpenCV project (and extra modules) as release version, and I reference it in my project. I was under the impression, that this would not matter, as I do not want to debug OpenCV itself .... or am I wrong?

Comment: That's a problem, since that ends up mixing together the two Visual C++ runtimes (debug and release)...and (AFAIK, it's true till at least 2015, haven't tried further versions) they're not compatible. Even the standard releases of OpenCV binaries contain the two builds for this reason.

Comment: Ah, I see. Coming from a .NET-world I was under the impression that it was the same runtime, with the only difference that release configurations are extremely optimized and do not carry (any) debug symbols.... which would only prevent debugging of the library project - but not the main one. Thank you very much for clearing that up!

Comment: It may be something else, but I've seen a lot of very odd issues related to this. Do try with a debug build of the libraries, and update the question if the problem still persists. (Also, what version of OpenCV is this?)

Comment: I will rebuild it in debug mode and update the question tomorrow. I am using OpenCV v4.0